# What does an asterisk mean at the beginning of an AHK script's line?

Tags: syntax, autohotkey

I'm trying to modify an AHK script I like but don't quite completely understand.

What does the asterisk mean at the beginning of this line of script?

`*capslock::`

Does the pair of colons at the end mean this line is only part of the statement? Does it continue to the next line?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fires the hotkey regardless of the modifiers being held down.

http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm

> Wildcard: Fire the hotkey even if extra modifiers are being held down. This is often used in conjunction with remapping keys or buttons. For example:
>
> Win+C, Shift+Win+C, Ctrl+Win+C, etc. will all trigger this hotkey.
>
> ```
> *#c::Run Calc.exe
> ```
>
> Pressing Scrolllock will trigger this hotkey even when modifer key(s) are down.
>
> ```
> *ScrollLock::Run Notepad
> ```

Edit:
Hm, didn't see the second part.

If you have a single statement, you put it all on one line like above. If you have multiple statements, you must put a newline after the `::` and have a `return` at the end.

```
#w:: MsgBox "Windows+W FTW"
#q::
  MsgBox "Windows+Q FTW"
  MsgBox "Another annoying message box!"
  return
```

I have a way of using the `capslock` key as a modifier that I like better:

```
;; make capslock a modifier, make shift-capslock a true capslock
setcapslockstate, OFF ;SetCapsLockState, alwaysoff

$*Capslock::   ; $ means that the hotkey code shouldn't trigger its own hotkey
  Gui, 99:+ToolWindow 
  Gui, 99:Show, x-1 w1 +NoActivate, Capslock Is Down 
  keywait, Capslock 
  Gui, 99:Destroy 
  return 

; Made a window show up when the capslock is pressed.

; Now, if that hidden windown is there, do anything you like
#IfWinExist, Capslock Is Down 
   j::Left 
   k::Right 
   i::Up 
   m::Down 
#IfWinExist 

; Oh, by the way, right-alt and capslock works like real capslock
ralt & Capslock::
  GetKeyState, capstate, Capslock, T
  if capstate = U
  {
    SetCapsLockState, on
  } else {
    SetCapsLockState, off
  }
  return
```

Comment: For more modern versions of AHK you'll have to remove the plus sign in `+NoActivate` for it to work. Otherwise, It worked great. Thanks!